# Internal server error aws lambda function nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying out a demo with AWS lambda function using Axios and Cheerio, I am getting back response after calling the endpoint as {message: Internal Server Error}

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {

       const axios = require('axios');
       const cheerio = require('cheerio');
         axios.get('https://www.kitco.com').then((response) => {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const ask = $('#AU-ask').text();
            const bid = $('#AU-bid').text();
            const resbid = bid.slice(0,7);
            const resask = ask.slice(0,7);
            const result = {
                "ask": resask,
                "bid": resbid
            }
            return result;

        }); 
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': result
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response 

};
```

Comment: Is the handler being called? Call your handler ``handler ``. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html. Could you please provide more descriptions on the error?

Comment: Yes the error of internal server is after the API Gateway endpoint link in clicked in the browser which in turn calls the handler

Comment: Call you handler ``handler`` it is important to comply with the API. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Just tried, same issue, response is an {message:Internal Server Error}

Answer (score 1):

`result` is clearly not in `response` scope, therefore this will result in a typical `undefined` error.

The solution would be to handle the logic inside `axios.get` callback, try this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

exports.lambdaHandler = (event, context) => {
  axios.get('https://www.kitco.com')
    .then((response) => {
      const html = response.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const ask = $('#AU-ask').text();
      const bid = $('#AU-bid').text();
      const resbid = bid.slice(0, 7);
      const resask = ask.slice(0, 7);

      const result = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: {
          ask: resask,
          bid: resbid
        }
      };

      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get error detail in monitor tab of Lambda console web. I guest you get back an error like `response is undefined` in `return response` line.

With your code, `return response` line will be execute immediately when you call the function, but `response` did not defined in the `lambdaHandler` scope.

I recommended that, don’t mix `async/await` syntax with Promise syntax (.then .catch), just use one of them, I suggest use `async/await` syntax.

The function will like:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
    const response = await axios.get('https://www.kitco.com'); // wait until we get the response

    const html = response.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const ask = $('#AU-ask').text();
    const bid = $('#AU-bid').text();
    const resbid = bid.slice(0, 7);
    const resask = ask.slice(0, 7);

    const result = {
      "ask": resask,
      "bid": resbid
    }

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result), // If you working with lambda-proxy-integrations, the `body` must be a string
    }; // return to response the request
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return {
      statusCode: 500, // Example, http status will be 500 when you got an exception
      body: JSON.stringify({error: err}),
    }
  }
};
```